# Rails Ajaxified form doesn't render errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement a simple uniqueness validation on a Rails Ajaxified form. Unfortunately, my validation error is not printed when the validation is not accepted. Can you help me to figure why?

**model.rb**

```
class WaitingList < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

**controller.rb**

```
def create_concours
    @email = params[:email]
    @waiting_user = WaitingList.new(email: @email, source: params[:source], concours_city: params[:choosen_city])
    #First Ajax of Weekendr History snif
    respond_to do |format|
    if @waiting_user.save
        UserMailer.welcome(@email).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to concours_path }
        format.js
      else
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag concours_path, {id: 'concours-form', remote: true} do %>
                <%= text_field_tag :email,
                    value = nil,
                    class: "landing-form-input",
                    autocomplete: "off",
                    required: true,
                    pattern: '[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}',
                    placeholder: "Renseignez ton email ici"
                  %>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :choosen_city, '', id: 'c-choosen-city'%>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'source', params[:source] %>
                <%= button_tag :submit, class: "landing-form-button" do %>
                    Je tente ma chance !
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
```

**create_concours.js.erb**

```
function refreshForm(innerHTML) {
  const form = document.getElementById("concours-form");
  form.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}

<% if @waiting_user.errors.any? %>
  refreshForm('<%= j render "form" %>');
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand you question please correct me. In the create_concours.js.erb it renders form and the form does not show any error right ? If so, form should be like form_tag @waiting_user do |f| and inputs should be like f.text_field ...

Comment: Yes for now, It renders a blank form with no error. The form is working well. The only thing missing is the alert about uniqueness on the rendered form after the error raised

Comment: You should use this style if you want to display errors https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

Comment: I don't understand if I change to a form for it's giving me a "NoMethodError in Pages#concours" :( `<%= @form_for waiting_user, {id: 'concours-form', action: 'create_concours', remote: true} do |f| %>`

Comment: You should do `@waiting_user = WaitingUser.new` in new action which is form rendered.Than you should use `form_for @waiting_user`

Comment: I think this is what I do : I have a `@waiting_user = WaitingList.new` in my `get 'concours', to: 'pages#concours' ` and for my `post 'concours', to: 'pages#create_concours' ` i got the upon create_concours method. Is it a wrong way of doing ?

Comment: Why don’t you create concours controller and use crud methods ?

Comment: I thought it would be wise to limit the number of controllers I have. Is it not?

Comment: http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/